# Silent mode on Z1 Compact Lollipop 5.1?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, 5.1-lollipop, silent-mode, sony-xperia-z1

I have a Sony Z1 Compact. Android 5.0 had a beautiful silent mode. Pushing the power button the screen went on, locked, and when you pressed the volume button you could set it to silent, optionally for several hours.

Recently I've upgraded to Android 5.1, and this option has disappeared. The strange thing is that when I [google](https://www.androidpit.com/android-5-1-lollipop-silent-mode) for this, I find that Android 5.0 had no silent mode, and 5.1 has exactly what I want and how it was for 5.0 on my phone.

**How can I use silent mode on my Z1C with Lollipop 5.1?**

Comment: Tried Volume down > Priority Interuption?

Comment: When the phone is locked, and I press volume down (or up), I see the volume bar and I can set the volume. On the right side I see a menu button. When I press that it opens a menu for Ringtone, Mediavolume and Alarm. That's it.

Comment: @SPRBRN Ahh, I have Lollipop 5.0, and it has the None, Priority and ALL options.(even if the screen is locked). Have you installed some custom ROM? May be you can install some Notification bar widget to switch on the silent profile.(some apps doing this requires root though). So is your device rooted?

Comment: @TechMod, that was the solution! If you want the points, make it an answer!

Answer (score 0):

Just press the volume-rocker while the screen is locked. Then choose the ringing-mode by pressing the bell-icon on the left side of the volume-slider until the phone is silenced.